# getElementsByTagName within a getElementByID

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to grab all  tags within a div called "states", and then uncheck them (they are all checkboxes).

```
document.getElementById("states").getElementsByTagName("input").checked = false;
```

For some reason it's not working, though it DOES work if I give them each IDs and use this code for each:

```
document.getElementById("checkboxName").checked = false;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName() returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). A NodeList does not have a 'checked' property, is a collection of Nodes. What you're trying to do would be very easy with jQuery. But you cand do it your way, just enumerate the NodeList with a for loop (NodeList is Array-like) and change the checked property.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById("states").getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) checkboxes[i].checked = false;
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#states input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
```

check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5VaL/)

Comment: aww ... you beat me, you have been faster :D +1

Comment: Huh...it works, but I'm getting a type error, saying that "checkboxes[i] is undefined"  --that doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Edited the answer with a jsfiddle. Check for any difference with your code, because the error doesn't make sense to me, either.

Comment: The OP could also use querySelectorAll: `var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#states input[type="checkbox"]');`. Giving all the subject inputs the same class will also work.

Comment: That's true RobG. Accustomed to use that in jQuery, but I'm not used to pure querySelector() at all.

Comment: Oscar...here's my code: 
var inputTags = document.getElementById("states").getElementsByTagName("input");
   for (var x=0; x <= inputTags.length; x++ ) {
    inputTags[x].checked = false;
   }

Comment: Okay. The problem is the 'x <= inputTags.length' part. NodeList indexes, like array indexes, are zero-based. The last value for x will be inputTags.length, but the last valid value is inputTags.length - 1. Change the '<=' to '<'.

Comment: Ohhhhhh...I was thinking in reverse!  Totally missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList. On it you can just do a simple for loop and set checked for each element. Setting the same id for each one of them is not a correct way of doing this as semantically there shouldn't be more than one element with the same id.

Comment: Thanks for the response...I wasn't setting the same ID for each input tag--I was just showing what I would do for each of them.

Comment: Also...shouldn't I still be able to operate on all of those <input> tags in the manner above?  I understand that it returns a nodeList, but why can't I apply .checked to all of the nodes it returns via the above method?

Comment: Oh, Whoops, just saw the above.  Thanks!!